# Is there any downside to initializing Fabric & Crashlytics at the Application level?

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-android

In the official documentation of Crashlytics it shows initializing Fabric in the onCreate method of an activity. I would like to have Crashlytics report crashes across the entire app, is there any downside to putting the initialization call at the Application level? Will making this change be sufficient in receiving crash reports across the entire app?

Example from documentation:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

How I would like to do it:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

In my testing this seems to work for my purposes, but I want to make sure this is not an anti-pattern since I can't seem to find any documentation on on it.

Comment: I like to init Fabric in Application level itself.

Comment: @SarthakMittal I agree and it seems like the best way to do it. There must be a reason it is not documented this way, right? Perhaps it is because most beginner apps do not subclass Application? Either way I just want to make sure there will be no unintended consequences of switching to init at Application level

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. Yes, you can and should move it to the Application's sub-classed `onCreate()` if you have it. For [reference](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/overview.html?highlight=application#getting-started):

"If you have an Application subclass, then you can place `Fabric.with()` in the `onCreate()` method. Otherwise, if you have multiple launch activities in your app, then add `Fabric.with()` to each launch activity. Fabric is only initialized the first time you call start, so calling it multiple times won’t cause any issues."

Answer (score 1):

Application is what lives till your android app process is killed.
You can use this to stored Application specific data (as long as your application is alive) that may be used across various activities.

As Fabric needs to initialized when application launched so its better to initialize it in Application class.

Comment: I can see what you mean, but it is not documented this way in their official documentation

Comment: Official Documentation of fabric mention that  If you have an Application subclass, then you can place Fabric.with() in the onCreate() method. Otherwise, if you have multiple launch activities in your app, then add Fabric.with() to each launch activity. Fabric is only initialized the first time you call start, so calling it multiple times won’t cause any issues.